# Call Activity method from Adapter (ViewHolder)

Tags: android

I have a class where I define a recycler view with some buttons. In the relative adapter, I add a onClick method for every button. From the onClick method, I need to call a method in another activity. How can I do? I've tried this but it doesn't work, unless I put the method to be called in the first activity.

First Activity, where I declare the RecyclerView:

public class Classici_Tab extends Fragment {

```
LinkedList<Book> catalog = new LinkedList<>();

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
BookListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classici_tab, container, false);

    fillCatalog("catalog.csv");     //fill the LinkedList

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.classici_rv);
    mAdapter = new BookListAdapter(getContext(), catalog);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return fragmentView;
}
}
```

}

The Adapter:

```
public class BookListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookListAdapter.BookViewHolder> {

    static Drawable borrow_top;
    static Drawable reserve_top;

    public BookListAdapter()
    {}

    // View Holder
    class BookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public final Button borrow;
        public final Button addfavorites;
        final BookListAdapter mAdapter;


        public BookViewHolder(final View itemView, BookListAdapter adapter) {
            super(itemView);
            borrow = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.borrow);
            addfavorites = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.addfavorites);

            this.mAdapter = adapter;

            addfavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final int cover_book = R.id.cover;
                    final String title_book = title.getText().toString();
                    final String author_book = author.getText().toString();

                    add_to_fav(itemView, new Book(cover_book, title_book, author_book));    //METHOD TO BE CALLED
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private LinkedList<Book> mBookList = new LinkedList<>();            //per Classici_Tab TODO
    private LinkedList<Book> mBookListFavorites = new LinkedList<>();     //per Favorites_page
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    boolean isVisible = false;
    public ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback;

    ClickListener clickListener;

    public BookListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<Book> bookList) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mBookList = bookList;
    }

    @Override
    public BookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_list_item, parent, false);
        return new BookViewHolder(mItemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final BookViewHolder holder, int position) {
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        ...
    }

    //INTERFACE TO CALL THE METHOD (IN THE SECOND ACTIVITY)
    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void add_to_fav(View v, Book book)
    {
        if(clickListener != null)
        {
            clickListener.itemClicked(v, book);
        }
    }

    public interface ClickListener
    {
        void itemClicked(View view, Book book);
    }
}
```

Second Activity, where I declare the method:

```
public class Favorites_Page extends Activity implements BookListAdapter.ClickListener {

    RecyclerView favorites_rv;
    BookListAdapter mAdapter_List;
    LinkedList<Book> favorites = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorites_page);

        favorites_rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.favorites_rv);
        favorites_rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        favorites_rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAdapter_List = new BookListAdapter();
        mAdapter_List.clickListener = (BookListAdapter.ClickListener)this;
    }


    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, Book book) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the method has been called successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have only one activity running at a time, you can't call a method in a different activity. In any case you have to start a second activity with an intent and pass the data it needs as extras in the intent.

Answer (score 0):

You need serialization to communicate between 2 activities. For example :

```
addfavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int cover_book = R.id.cover;
            final String title_book = title.getText().toString();
            final String author_book = author.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent( CurrentActivityClass.this, Favorites_Page.class )
            intent.putExtra(Favorites_Page.KEY_BOOK , Book) // Book need to implements Parcelable (or Serializable if all content is Serializable)
           CurrentActivityClass.this.startActivity(intent)
        }
    });
```

then from your fav activity you get data like this :

```
public class Favorites_Page extends Activity {

    public static final String KEY_BOOK = "book"
    RecyclerView favorites_rv;
    BookListAdapter mAdapter_List;
    LinkedList<Book> favorites = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.favorites_page);

        ...

        Book book = getIntent().getExtra(KEY_BOOK)
        ...
    }
...
```

Comment: By doing this, I recall the onCreate method of the Activity. But I don't want to do this, I want to recall a method that I defined in that Activity. How?

Comment: You can't assume your activity will still exist when returning to it, system can destroy an activity to free memory for example so you need to handle its recreation, you cannot communicate between activities with a simple listener/callback